# Real multiple class inheritance, not a collection of methods via traits

Tags: php

I understand the way you `extend` a class like `ChildClass extends ParentClass`, I understand use of `class abstraction` and `interfaces`, and I do understand `traits`

In the articles I have read most of people stated that traits is used in practice to achieve multiple inheritance that is not done by `extends` functionality as it supports only single extension.

As I understand traits it is more of a collection of functions that can be used by different classes or other traits.

In this question I ask you to tell me how is it correctly done to literally do extension of more than one class not adding some function-collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can be extremely clear about this:

PHP *does not* allow this.

I indeed believe that traits provides a way to achieve multiple inheritance, under some restricted conditions. If your codebase is extremely OOP pure and well designed, traits may allow you to achieve multiple inheritence.

But it's not a catch all. If this is a stumbling block for you, don't blame this on PHP's design, you probably need to think about a different way to do what you want. (for example: delegate instead of sub-class).

Comment: thanks, that's correct indeed. It's just I don't do a work now and I think I find some ways around when I do. I just needed to get sure that `traits` is really a collection of methods that does not really do much for you to do multiple inheritances.